# JSON not parsing correctly using JSON.parse but $.parseJSON works

Tags: javascript, json

In JS I have a string variable as follows:
Text JSON Data:

```json
[{ "id" : "3", "parent" : "2", "text" : "Lack of Survey Information" },{ "id" : "4", "parent" : "3", "text" : "Lack of Surveyor Resource" },{ "id" : "5", "parent" : "3", "text" : "Land access unavailable" },{ "id" : "2", "parent" : "1", "text" : "Design Incorrect" },{ "id" : "1", "parent" : "16", "text" : "Abortive Work" },{ "id" : "6", "parent" : "1", "text" : "Wrong design info used in construction" },{ "id" : "16", "parent" : "#", "text" : "a" }]
```

This is output from the following code:

```
            console.log("Text JSON Data:"+strJSON)
        var objJSON=$.parseJSON(strJSON)
        var objJSON=JSON.parse(strJSON)
```

It parses using $.parseJSON but does not parse using JSON.parse (I get a bizarre "Uncaught TypeError: JSON.parse is not a function" error though it clearly is).  I am using Chrome.  It gets weirder, when I just use $.parseJSON successfully and then use JSON.stringify on the returned JSON object it crashes and also throws up an error.

What is weird is that I pass several other JSON strings to this function and they are parsed fine.  I thought it might be something to do with the '#' symbol but it seems to parse OK in JSFiddle.  I know when using VBA that sometimes an error code is triggered for a line of code when in fact the error is caused by something else.  I am wondering if that is what is going on here.

**What I need to understand is why this particular string is triggering the bizarre errors.**

Comment: Why is `JSON.parse` clearly a valid function?

Comment: JSON.parse works well, if you use the string version of the JSON that you have provided. But you are not supposed to pass JSON in JSON.parse.

Comment: JSON.parse is a valid function because I am using Jquery and it is a function:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: `JSON.parse` should be part of any modern browser. It sounds like it has been inadvertantly overwritten/reassigned to something else (not a function)

Comment: `JSON.parse is a valid function because I am using Jquery`, `JSON.parse` has nothing to do with jQuery, it is an API provided by the browser itself.

Comment: What does `console.dir(JSON);` show in the console of your browser if you place it right before the line `var objJSON=JSON.parse(strJSON)`?

Comment: if I put in console.dir(objJSON) before var objJSON=JSON.parse(strJSON)  I get "Array(7)
0: {id: '3', parent: '2', text: 'Lack of Survey Information'}
1: {id: '4', parent: '3', text: 'Lack of Surveyor Resource'}
2: {id: '5', parent: '3', text: 'Land access unavailable'}
3: {id: '2', parent: '1', text: 'Design Incorrect'}
4: {id: '1', parent: '16', text: 'Abortive Work'}
5: {id: '6', parent: '1', text: 'Wrong design info used in construction'}
6: {id: '16', parent: '#', text: 'a'}
length: 7
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)"

Comment: You've globally injected over-top of JSON somewhere and it's conflicting big time. There's no reason that should fault in any browser, only errors you should be seeing is invalid token/etc. Follow the advice below and console JSON function itself.

Comment: No, @t.niese asked you to do `console.dir(JSON)` not `console.dir(objJSON)`. What does `console.dir(JSON)` give you? (unless that was just a typo in your comment!)

Comment: @phuzi good catch, I didn't read that comment correctly. @AndrewWatts I specifically asked about `console.dir(JSON)` because I want to figure out if you have overwritten `JSON`.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I misunderstood.  Yes it seems I have overwritten JSON with another object in my code but I can't find "JSON=" anywhere in my code.  I guess I will have done it in a more indirect way.  I will do some more digging.  thanks for the help all.

Comment: You could place the code of this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxgm73tk/1/), before any other code is loaded, and the debugger of the dev tools of your browser should break when you overwrite `JSON`. In the call stack you will then see where it happened. Just place it in a `<script></script>` right a the beginning of your `<head>`

Comment: Another thing you could check if `console.dir(window.JSON)` and `console.dir(JSON)` are different, if that's the case you have some variable shadowing going on. Or better use the `Scope` information in the dev tools.